# How can I add Board Shape to output job in Altium Designer?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-fabrication

When I want to add board shape to final output in **output job**, I draw board shape on a useless layer and then I add that layer to output job.

Is it possible to add board shape automatically in Altium Designer?

Comment: In older versions of Altium, it was common to use the Keepout layer to define the board outline (along with any internal keep-outs). It's probably still a good practice to add a keep-out around the perimeter of the board. Your drill drawing should also have an outline of the board in order to document the board dimensions.

Comment: Related: [Correct way to define board outline?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/159720/)

Comment: Also, if you use ODB++ output, it will include board outline data separate from any layer data.

Comment: Finally, if your fab shop wants the board outline on a gerber layer, there is a command "Create Primitives from Board Outline" (IIRC) that makes it very easy to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately that isn't possible. As far as I know the industry-accepted standard (et least here in Europe it's pretty clear) is to use Mechanical 1 for the board outline. Mechanical 1 will contain the board outline, including possible cutouts but nothing else. Provide that to your PCB manufacturer and you should be fine.

Comment: Fabs I have used will just look at all the gerbers together and use any one that has what looks like a board outline as the board outline. Typically this means the Keepout layer or Drill Drawing layer defines the board dimensions, if no mechanical layer has been dedicated just to that purpose.